# How to configure whitelist in mongodb by mac address

Tags: mongodb

I need to permit connection with certains pcs filter by mac address or motherboard. I know how to filter by IP address but This don't required.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something MongoDB supports. In fact I doubt this is possible at all in any environment that uses NAT (i.e. residential internet connections with a router) since the NAT gateway would create traffic from its own MAC address.

You may be able to do this using firewall software, see for example http://openbsd-archive.7691.n7.nabble.com/PF-filtering-on-MAC-address-td221756.html.